# How protect music file downloaded by my music app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, security, encryption

I am need a solution for protect music file downloaded in an music app.

We have all rights for the audios, so, we need to garante only our app is able to play this audios.

This music app actually is only for streaming. The next update is for implement the functionality for download e play music offline.

I know Spotify , for example, use DRM protection, but it is a little bit controvercious for some people, and I think this is not what we need now.

During my researches, I dont find any concrete solution. So, my questions are which functionalities, libraries or resources can I use to protect the downloaded files.

Maybe I need to encrypt/decrypt the files? But, Swift have a native functionality for this, and have some documentation available?

So, what can I use to protect the audios with Swift, and keep playing the audio only in my own app?

Answer (score 0):

This question gets asked almost daily and the answer is, and will always be, the same - if a user can play your audio on their device, then they can also extract and keep a copy of that audio - no amount of DRM, encryption or any other naive concept anyone dreams up can change this.

You can prevent "script kiddies" from just copying the files off their phone by embedding an encryption key in your app and streaming files through a stream cipher before playing them, but again, it's trivial to reverse engineer and get the key.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So, you think use any type of "secure" in this case is trivial? Even if it is to prevent anyone from getting the file so easily? The intention would be to at least make it a little difficult, without getting so simple someone copy the files to other devices. But I understand that there is no 100% method and that just someone wants to go through it.

Answer (score 0):

### You can transcode your .mp3 files to HLS file which will generate one master playlist and several segment files and then you can apply ALS encryption on it using ffmpeg or Apple Media segmenter.

### For More Info:

https://www.theoplayer.com/blog/content-protection-for-hls-with-aes-128-encryption

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Your information is helping me a lot. For now i am search a little more about AES, and found a lot of libraries and to Apple CryptoKit. 
I am studying some of them to see if that is what we need. 
So I confirm and mark your answer as correct.Thank you.